# Xamarin + VS2017 BreakPoint on ClassLibrary not working

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, portable-class-library

I've read related questions and tried those solutions but not working thou (like unchecking `Enable Just My Code` and etc).

The Problem is breakpoint does not stop code at external Class Libraries, I separated my `UI` (Portable Class Library that contains `App.xaml` class) and my `database/models` (Portable Class library that contains my objects + database related classes), breakpoints are working  in `UI` Class library but non of them are working in Database (eg. I put a debug log and it's shown in `out put` window but the break point on it does NOT work!)

Also my code is working but i'm not able to debug database using breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer! this is a kind of bug at Visual Studio 2017.

- Go to `\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter`
- Open `Xamarin.Common.targets` file (using text editor)
- Replace this string: `DependsOnTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration;AllProjectOutputGroups"` **To** `DependsOnTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration;_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence;AllProjectOutputGroups"`

  You can find about this bug [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52760)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the breakpoint was hited in iOS project but not on PCL
I was able to resolve this using the workaround described here:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56893

Open the portable class library .csproj file in a text editor. For example, right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and select Unload Project, and then right-click it again and select "Edit ...".
Under the PropertyGroup for the "Debug|AnyCPU" configuration, change the DebugType to:
portable

Hope this will help